# match two mesh curves

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I've got a situation where two objects meet and they both have curves.  I need to make the white portion on the left side match the curve of the gray portion on the left side.  The inside the white area isn't really a curve, its the gray portion showing through.

I've tried cutting, scaling, and just can't get it to look right.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Gwfami

[image]

Comment: It' s unclear which "portions" meet. The inside? Explain again.

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the misunderstanding.  I ended up hand matching each portion so that the curves lined up properly.  I was looking for an easier, automated route instead of a manual labor intensive version.[image]

Comment: I think this could have been easily done using booleans. Look at this workflow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gj2ZjpiDUWY

Comment: Thanks.  That gives me some ideas.